# Install mongodb with lumen in widows system

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, lumen

I want to use mongodb with lumen framework (which is micro framework of laravel)

I have followed steps

1. check from my computer my system in 64bit windows
2. download dll file for 64 bit for mongodb download two zips and try both php_mongodb-1.5.3-7.0-nts-vc14-x64.zip , php_mongodb-1.5.3-7.0-ts-vc14-x64.zip
   3.put dll file in php/ext
3. enable extension for mongodb in php.ini file `extension=php_mongodb.dll`
4. restart apache

now I want use `jenssegers/mongodb`

I have fire command as below:

```
composer require jenssegers/mongodb
```

It gives bwlow error

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'E:\xampp7\php\ext\php_mongodb.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'E:\xampp7\php\ext\php_mongodb.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
 in Unknown on line 0
```

I have check phpinfo , it not shows me detail of mongo

Comment: Do you have 32 or 64 bit PHP? And how have you verified this?

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/homestead is a solution for this and much more, very handy.